# Snakemake: using regex in rule run

Tags: python, snakemake

i am new in sankemake, i am trying to run this code but i have an error.
I have my input directories structured like this:

```
Library:
    -MMETSP1:
        SRR1_1.fastq.gz
        SRR1_2.fastq.gz
    -MMETSP2:
        SRR2_1.fastq.gz
        SRR2_2.fastq.gz
```

So what i want to do is to run the rule twice for each directory. For tht i have used the expand function in rule all and i have two jobs counted by snakemake. That is fine for me. But my probelm is not to retrieve the fasta file inside my directories. **For that i have used regex in the execution of the command but it is not working**.
Can someone help me please.
Thank you in advance !

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import glob
import sys

SALMON_BY_LIBRARY_DIR = OUT_DIR + "salmon_by_library_out"
salmon = config["software"]["salmon"]


(LIBRARY, FASTQ, SENS) = glob_wildcards(LIBRARY_DIR + "{mmetsp}/{reads}_{type}.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:
        salmon_by_library_out = expand(SALMON_BY_LIBRARY_DIR + "/" + "{mmetsp}", zip, mmetsp=LIBRARY),

rule salmon_by_library:
   input:
        transcript = TRINITY_DIR + "/Trinity.fasta",
        fastq = LIBRARY_DIR + "{mmetsp}",
   output:
        salmon_out = directory(SALMON_BY_LIBRARY_DIR + "/" + "{mmetsp}"),
   log:
       OUT_DIR + "{mmetsp}/salmon.log"
   threads:
       config["threads"]["salmon"]
   params:
       trimmomatic_dir = directory(TRIMMOMATIC_DIR)
   run:
      shell(""" mkdir -p {output.salmon_out}/index """)

      shell("""
      {salmon}
      index \
      -t {input.transcript} \
      -i {output.salmon_out}/index \
      --type quasi \
      -k 31 \
      -p {threads} > {log} &&

       {salmon}
       quant \
       -i {output.salmon_out}/index \
       -l A \
       -1 {input.fastq}/*_1.fastq.gz \
       -2 {input.fastq}/*_2.fastq.gz \
       -o {output.salmon_out} \
       -p {threads} > {log}
        """)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an input function to retrieve the path to the fastq from the config. Did you do the official tutorial ( http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html)? It covers exactly this use case. For real world best practices I suggest to further have a look at https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/docs.